# Предложения со словом «надпись». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, двоеточие, выбор-варианта

Помогите разобраться с пунктуацией в данных предложениях:

1. Он подошёл к зданию и у центрального входа увидел надпись: "Открыто", однако дверь была закрыта.
2. Он увидел надпись: "Въезда нет!" и уехал.

Не могу найти примеры, в которых после двоеточия и последующего раскрытия содержания надписи либо выражения предложение продолжалось бы.

Comment: Я не вижу никакой необходимости использовать здесь двоеточие. А без него пунктуация очевидна. Вы уверены, что текст на табличках должен оформляться как прямая речь?

Comment: behemothus, В музее нет табличек с надписью: "Руками не трогать". Нужно ли здесь двоеточие?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Да, двоеточие нужно, пунктуация верна.

Comment: behemothus, Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться! Есть такое предложение: "Она сидела в его футболке с надписью "Пеле", которая была ей велика размера на два". С одной стороны, в справочнике Розенталя сказано, что перед словами "надпись", "выражение" и т.п. двоеточие ставится, с другой — многочисленные примеры из Национального корпуса показывают, что в подобных предложениях ставятся только кавычки. (Например, у Домбровского: "У резных ворот с надписью "За колхозное изобилие" толпились люди"). 

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Рекомендуем двоеточие поставить.

Comment: Для начала просьба: давать ссылки или хотя бы указывать точное место, где изложены положения, на которое вы ссылаетесь.  Я нашел, конечно, но потратил изрядно времени.

Comment: *Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!* - хорошо сказать... Справкино творчество (это вопрос 205531) я комментировать не буду, уровень отвечающих там довольно низкий. А вот в отношении Розенталя... Это примечание к п. 154 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154

Comment: Что могу сказать... Во-первых, у Лопатина уже нет этого примечания. Во-вторых, в одном их примеров у Розенталя у меня сомнения. Как раз с табличкой. Не уверен я, что двоеточие там нужно даже по тем, розенталевским правилам.. Два других примера сомнений не вызывают.

Comment: В целом, я вижу, что Розенталя неоравдано расширительно трактуют. Когда за подобным словом (надпись, подпись) идет длинный текст, двоеточие понятно - мы имеем дело с неким аналогом прямой речи. Но ведь так же можно до абсурда дойти. Например: *[В таких-то случаях] перед перекрестком устанавливается знак "Стоп"* - Ну какое тут может быть двоеточие? Тут как бы не прямая речь, а **название** знака (таблички).

Comment: Вот все, что могу предложить в качестве объяснения. Ну еще признать, что единого подхода тут, видимо, нет. Правило в формулировке Р., видимо, нуждается  в уточнении. А на практике двоеточие лучше не ставить, если не хочется. Примерно так. Вот в ваших примерах реально не хочется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Если **напрямую** следовать указаниям Розенталя, то надо делать так.

> Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова *предложение, **надпись**, выражение* и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие, например: *Над воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: «Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные, также отдаются напрокат и починяются старые»* (Пушкин).

**Он подошёл к зданию и у центрального входа увидел надпись: "Открыто", однако дверь была закрыта.**
**Он увидел надпись: "Въезда нет!" — и уехал.** (Прямая речь заканчивается восклицательным знаком, поэтому ставится **тире**.)

На красном сафьяновом переплёте золотом вытеснен его псевдоним и **надпись: "Кругосветное путешествие пешком",** а все страницы заляпаны печатями ― простыми, сургучными, радужными наклейками, гербовыми марками, ярлычками гостиниц, подписями губернаторов и консулов. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 2 (1964)]

И вот в дружбе с Левкой Шулепниковым, которая крепла ― Лёвка непонятно почему льнул к Глебову, приглашал домой, дарил книги, к которым сам был равнодушен, ко всем книгам вообще, и было подозрение, что потаскивал из отцовской библиотеки, потому что на некоторых стояли сделанные синей печатью изображения человека с молотом, лучи солнца и **надпись: "Из книг А. В. Ш.", ―** даже в мальчишеском приятельстве отец видел какие-то опасности и предлагал "не высовываться". [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)] (Запятая + тире от вставки.)

2. Если же текст надписи вводится в состав предложения, то работают обычные правила пунктуации.

**Он подошёл к зданию и у центрального входа увидел надпись "Открыто", однако дверь была закрыта.**
**Он увидел надпись "Въезда нет!" и уехал.**

Пуговицы, если перевернуть их, имели на тыльной чёрной стороне их тисненную в металле **надпись "Чикаго, Иллинойс, Ю. С."** ― они поставлялись Америкой по ленд-лизу. [Эдуард Лимонов. У нас была Великая Эпоха (1987)]

Чаще всего как прямая речь (то есть с двоеточием) оформляются **распространенные** надписи, находящиеся в самом конце предложения (Нацкорпус: [**надпись**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&endyear=2019&p=0)).
Если в предложении имеется [**с надписью**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8E&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&endyear=2019&p=2), то большинство таких "надписных слов" являются частью самого предложения (*с надписью **какой?***; без двоеточия).

Вот интересное предложение:

Она открыла блокнот **с надписью "Записки Дария",** подумала и написала: "Нелёгкое это дело, доложу я вам, уважать себя и других. [Наталия Ермильченко. Колыбельная // «Мурзилка», 2000]

Если бы мне пришлось выбирать, я бы включила Ваши "Открыто" и "Въезда нет!" в предложение (второй вариант).

[§122. Прямая речь внутри авторских слов](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm)

Comment: "Он увидел надпись: «Въезда нет!» - и уехал. (Прямая речь заканчивается восклицательным знаком, поэтому ставится тире.)" Если бы после слов "въезда нет" не было восклицательного знака, то и тире не ставилось бы? Но почему тогда так: "Она сказала: «Нынче говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются науками» — и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку (Л. Толстой)" Почему без восклицательных и вопросительных знаков после прямой речи есть тире? "Она сказала и подозвала" - разве тут есть причина для постановки тире?

Comment: Совершенно верно. Это правила оформления прямой речи внутри слов автора: _Если прямая речь стоит внутри авторских слов, то перед ней ставится двоеточие, а после нее – запятая или тире (по условиям контекста)._  Если хотите, можно добавить другую ссылку в ответ.

Comment: _Почему без восклицательных и вопросительных знаков после прямой речи есть тире?_ Потому что перед прямой речью ставится двоеточие, а после нее  — или запятая (если она необходима в авторском предложении), или тире (если такой запятой в контексте нет). В предложении Толстого перед "и" нет запятой (Она сказала и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку), поэтому — для отделения прямой речи — перед "и" **необходимо** поставить тире.

Comment: Вот еще объяснение: **Тире** после прямой речи ставится, если на месте разрыва слов автора прямой речью **не должно быть** никаких знаков препинания. _Одна пушкинская строка: «Тяжелёшенько вздохнула» — говорит больше, чем могли бы сказать целые страницы прозы или стихов_ (С. Маршак). https://lingvotech.com/znaki_prepinaniya_pri_pryamoy_rechi

Comment: То есть в моем предложении (Он увидел надпись: "Въезда нет!" - и уехал) даже при отсутствии восклицательного знака надо было бы ставить тире? Тогда мне непонятно Ваше объяснение: "Прямая речь заканчивается восклицательным знаком, поэтому ставится тире". Это читается так, будто бы без восклицательного знака тире не было бы. Однако в моем предложении, если учесть Ваше недавнее пояснение, тире было бы вне зависимости от наличия восклицательного знака. Он увидел надпись: "Въезда нет" - и уехал.

Comment: Смысл этой фразы в том, что нам **все равно**, что там есть в тексте авторском на месте разрыва, главное — это наличие восклицательного знака. После него — всегда тире. Сравните: _Он увидел надпись: "Въезда нет!" — растерялся и уехал._ (А ведь **без** восклицательного знака нужно было бы поставить запятую. П-ф... Надеюсь, теперь понятно.